# Which was the first film adaptation of television series?

Tags: first-appearance, adaptation

Nowadays it seems that almost every successful television series winds up on the silver screen.  For a while, every series from the '60s and '70s was being made into a film - from *Mission Impossible* to *The Beverly Hillbillies*.

Before that, in the early days of television, Hollywood refused to admit to its existence on screen.  Television was seen as a competitor and no TV set was shown or mentioned.

So, what was the first television series to wind up on the cinema screen?
The earliest I can think of is [*The Quatermass Experiment*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0049646/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3) from 1955.  A Hammer Film adaptation of the BBC series that was itself an adaptation of a radio play.  Admittedly, not a Hollywood film.  Was there something earlier?  I'm sure there must be.

Comment: Not from TV, but from Book via Radio, so can't be an answer - War of the Worlds, book 1898, radio adaptation 1938, movie 1953 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_War_of_the_Worlds

Comment: The 1943 Batman film was also a TV serial. It was essentially an adaptation of itself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a [Dragnet film in 1954](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0046931/?ref_=fn_al_tt_3).  Dragnet was originally a radio program, but that program spawned a television series in 1951.

Answer (score -2):

Gunsmoke the movie was made in 1953

Comment: That wasn't an adaptation of the TV series, though. It was a completely unrelated production. The TV series only began in 1955.